# Video goes black after few seconds after replacing AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayeritem, avplayerlayer

Video plays perfectly fine when I play any video first time but when I pick a video from phone's gallery and replace it, the video goes black after 2 seconds and audio plays till the end.
Adding the video player here:

```
-(void) addMoviePlayer{
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"got1" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
AVPlayer *vidPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:item];
CGRect vidRect = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.15, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.3);

videoLayer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];
[videoLayer setPlayer:vidPlayer];
[videoLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[videoLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
videoLayer.frame = vidRect;
[self.view.layer addSublayer:videoLayer];
vidPlayer.muted = true;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:vidPlayer.currentItem];
}
```

Then I replace the AVPlayerItem with the one picked from gallery.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSLog(@"VideoURL = %@", videoURL);

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    AVPlayerItem *currentItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];
    [videoLayer.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:currentItem];
    [videoLayer.player play];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
-(void)playVideoFile:(NSURL *)fileUrl{ 

AVPlayer *videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:fileUrl];  
AVPlayerViewController *videoController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
videoController.player = videoPlayer;

[self presentViewController:videoController animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

Comment: Please go through my question first. This is certainly not what I am asking for.